# How to find entities where an array property of id's contains a certain id within typeorm

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm, typegraphql

I am creating a graphql api using nestjs, type-graphql and typeorm. I am having trouble finding out how to do a certain query. Let's say i have the following entities:

```js
@Entity()
@ObjectType({ description: 'The user model' })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(type => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  readonly id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @Field()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Field(type => [Project], { nullable: true })
  @ManyToMany(type => Project)
  @JoinTable()
  projects?: Project[];
}

@Entity()
@ObjectType({ description: 'The project model' })
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(type => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  readonly id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  description: string;

  @Field(type => [User], { nullable: true })
  @ManyToMany(type => User)
  @JoinTable()
  participants?: User[];
}
```

I have the following service:

```js
import { includes } from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Project)
    private projectRepository: Repository<Project>,
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
  async loadAllForUser(
    userId: string
  ): Promise<Project[]> {
    const projects = await this.projectRepository.find(
      {
          relations: ['participants'],
      },
    );

    return projects.filter(project =>
      includes(
        project.participants.map(participant => participant.id),
        userId,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this will be my resolver:

```js
@Resolver( of => Project)
export class ProjectResolver {
  constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}
  @Query(returns => [Project])
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
  async myProjects(
    @GqlUser() user: User,
  ) {
    return await this.projectService.loadAllForUser(
      user.id,
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see in my project service i am just fetching all the projects with the find method and then afterwards i am filtering this list using includes from lodash to filter out only the projects that contains the userid. Isn't there a way to add some sort of operation inside the find method of the project repository like a 'where' or 'in' so that i can filter it directly from there instead of manually filtering and using the includes from lodash? I even have no idea if this is even correct the way i am manually filtering?

Kind regards,

Gerry

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TypeORM QueryBuilder and make some inner joins to filter projects that does not belong to selected user.

Answer (score 0):

As of v0.3, you can use `ArrayContains()` to return a `FindOptionsWhere<>` type that we can use to filter the `where` clause on a relation.

```
where: {
  project: ArrayContains[participant.id]
}
```